# Some xbox parental control settings dont update in games

Tags: xbox-one, roblox, titanfall-2, trove

My Xbox account is a child account and my mom had the "see and upload community creations" to friends only, which prevented me from playing Roblox and Trove as well as preventing me from making or joining a network in Titanfall 2. As well as having cross-platform communications turned off and Xbox live chat on friends only. Recently, my mom changed all of the previously mentioned settings to Everyone. However, the "see and upload community creations" change to Everyone seemed to change nothing. Roblox and Trove still wont let me play, and Titanfall 2 still wont let me make/join a network. I HAVE removed and readded said games, restarted, logged out and in, and more. Also, I checked, and the changes did save.

Comment: Does it give you a specific message upon trying to use said apps?

Comment: Itsays whenever I try to use the above games/features it says something like "you cant ____because your restrictions prevent you from seeing community-created content" even though that ain't the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same exact thing you have to go to settings and select family then hit add person and it adds you to the family so you can do anything that your parents can do. Also if you have trouble just look up "How to add child to parents on Xbox."

Comment: I am in the family (as a child) and have been for years.

Comment: Yeah did it work though

Comment: umm, I haven't tried it yet and don't think I'll be able to.